# Complex eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, linear-algebra, eigenvector

I am facing an issue when using MATLAB eig function to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix.

The matrix D is
10x10 
all diagonal elements = 0.45 
all off-diagonal elements = -0.05

When using [vec, val] = eig(D) some of the resulting eigenvectors contain complex numbers  (i.e 0.3384 + 0.0052i). I have searched online and I found two related posts on similar issue, but did not help me in finding a solution.

So I tried the same subroutine in Python numpy (numpy.linalg.eigh(D)) and it gave me all real eigenvalues and eigenvectors. The results from Python are correct as I was able to verify my final results with a published paper.

My question is what causes MATLAB to give complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors for a symmetric matrix? Is there a way around it? I can certainly re-write my algorithm in Python, but I would rather avoid that.

Note: if I try 4x4 matrix with all diagonal elements = 0.375 and all off-diagonal elements = -0.125 then MATLAB eig(D) gave all real eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Thanks in advance for any advice on this issue.

Follow up. The code used to generate D and the eigenvalues/vectors:

```
    P = eye(10) - 1/10;
    delta = 1 - eye(10);
    A = -0.5 * delta;

    D = P*A*P;
    [vec val] =eig(D)
```

Comment: maybe this helps? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/309237

Comment: @amp Thanks, I saw this post before, but it did not help me with my problem. In fact, executing the example in that post does not give me complex eigenvectors.

Comment: So you're saying that `isreal(vec)` returns `0` for the code above for you? Is that actually the code you used when you got the complex values? How big are the imaginary parts? Are they virtually zero? What version of Matlab are you using (type `version` in your command window)?

Comment: @horchler Correct, isreal(vec) returns 0 and the code above is the exact code I used. The biggest virtual part in the eigenvector is +0.0052i and the MATLAB version is 7.13.0.564 (R2011b). And I responded to A. Donda below saying that my desktop does not give complex numbers, but my laptop does. I do not understand why (same OS, same MATLAB version)

Comment: You can use function `cdf2rdf` which converts complex matricies to real analogues without losing any precision http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cdf2rdf.html

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the problem using single precision.

```
  P = eye(10) - 1/10;
  delta = 1 - eye(10);
  A = -0.5 * delta;

  D = P*A*P;
  D = single(D)
  [vec val] =eig(D)
```

The results now are correct. Thank you all for taking the time responding to my question and thanks for all your suggestions. This is really more of a workaround than a solution. I still do not know why double precision causes complex eigenvectors.

Comment: This workaround may or may not work. To make sure that `D` is symmetric, better do `D = 0.5*(D+D')` instead of `D=single(D)`.

Answer (score 0):

Doing

```
D = 0.5 * eye(10) - 0.05 * ones(10);
eig(D)
```

I get

```
ans =
     -2.08166817117217e-17
                       0.5
                       0.5
                       0.5
                       0.5
                       0.5
                       0.5
                       0.5
                       0.5
                       0.5
```

which is not too bad. The first eigenvalue in the result should obviously be zero, so there's a rounding error, but otherwise the result is as expected. Due to the same issue of limited numerical precision I guess there could eventually be very small complex parts, too, but actually Matlab's `eig` should detect symmetry and produce only real-valued eigenvalues.

How exactly did you generate your matrix `D`? Maybe it has only approximately the structure you are describing?

Comment: I tried the way you generated the D and it works fine. So I guess like you said it is way the I computed D. This is how I generate my D. Eigenvalues are not a problem since the imaginary part is zero. But eigenvectors are the issue.

P = eye(10) - 1/10;
delta = 1 - eye(10);
A = -0.5 * delta;

D = P*A*P;
[vec val] =eig(D)

Comment: @user2471801, I suggest you include the code in the question text. That way it's easier for others to find, and read :-)

Comment: @RobertP. Thanks Robert P. I edited my post and added the code in a readable format.

Comment: @user2471801: I can't reproduce the problem. D generated with your code differs from my way on the order of rounding errors (1e-17) and its also not exactly symmetric anymore (again, to about 1e-17), but I still get only real-valued eigenvectors and -values. Eigenvalues similar as for mine, all 0.5 except for one close to zero – like it should be. Maybe you use `single` precision?

Comment: @A.Donda I am using double precision. I switched to single precision and it does not give complex numbers. Something is strange going on. My laptop gives complex numbers for D, but my desktop gives real numbers, using double precision. Both machines have same operating system and same version of MATLAB.

Comment: @user2471801 that is seriously strange. I've never heard of anything like that, but the only thing I can think about is that there is a hardware problem. (processor, or memory?) Not 100% sure, but in my understanding Matlab should give the exact same results on all platforms, because the numeric precision and the libraries used are identical.

Comment: @A.Donda I am glad you think that is strange too. I was also expecting MATLAB to gave same results on two different machines. I guess this is a question I need to post on the mathworks.com.

Comment: Yes, you should submit it as a "service request". Good luck!